# Bootstrap and angular - pass object to modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I create table using bootstrap and angular use object to display data. I want to open popup window to change object property by clicking row (and use angular binding in modal to work with object).
So my issue that i doesn't understand how to pass object from table to modal.

I found many examples with passing values and changing html on fly but in my case i want to use angular for binding and want to pass reference to object.

Sample of table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
            <thead>...</thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="property in properties" data-toggle="modal" data-id="property" data-target="#editPropertyModal">
                <td>{{property.name}}<td/>
                <td>{{property.value}}<td/>
                <td>...<td/>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

So by clicking this row i want to open modal and pass there property object and use controls like input, combobox to bind values via angular.
My sample of modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editPropertyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPropertyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="editPropertyModalLabel">Property details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{currentProperty.name}} - {{currentProperty.value}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My try to pass property via javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-editPropertyModal", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _self = $(this);
    var property = _self.data('id');
    $("#currentProperty").val(property);

    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Default Bootstrap JavaScript is not working well with angular, because it makes changes in DOM model outside AngularJS. Please consider using native directives for bootstrap, like these http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Also, for maximum simplicity, in many cases, you can use something like this plugin https://github.com/cgross/angular-prompt. It depends on bootstrap and gives you simple API based on promises.

```
prompt({
    title: 'Give me a name',
    message: 'What would you like to name it?',
    input: true,
    label: 'Name',
    value: 'Current name',
  }).then(function(name){
    //name contains new value
  });
```

Callback passed to `then` will be executed after clicking "OK" in popup.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Try to use angular-strap.
Also, as i understand i can do it manually. I can pass some string value to modal and then found object in scope by field and after pressing save button update object  in scope with value from popup. But it require much boilerplate code that i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to do that. It really helped me.